# DNS lookup on DNS server works, but wrong IP on clients

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnsmasq

I am trying to set up a DNS server to change a few domains in my local netwkork - first with bind9, then with dnsmasq. With both software, I resulted in the same problem: When executing nslookup / dig on the dns server itself, I am getting the correctly changed ip matches.

However, when doing a lookup on machines using the DNS server, it returns the wrong (original) host ip, instead of the modified one.

On the dns itself

```
nslookup mydomain.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   mydomain.com
Address: <correctly modified host ip>
```

On devices with flushed caches (mac / android):

```
nslookup mydomain.com
Server:     <dns server ip>
Address:    <dns server ip>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mydomain.com
Address: <original host ip>
```

The question is, why is the entry on the server correct, but faulty on the clients?

Comment: What do you mean "correctly modified"? Are you referring to the NAT addresses?

Comment: I am overriding a few domain entries with different IP addresses. With 'correctly modified', I mean it is the new host IP instead of the original one. The main problem is, why is the entry on the server correct but faulty on the clients using the exact same server?

Comment: TTL? Is that server the only one they get answers from?

Comment: server-side caching of entries is disabled during setup, TTL 0. The DNS server is the only one set on the clients. As nslookup / dig confirms, the answer is coming from this server.

Comment: Check `lsof -i:53 -nP` and evaluate which programs are listening on which interfaces. It's possible that you have port contention.

Comment: Does flushing dns entries on client help ? In Windows clients I would use `ipconfig /flushdns` in command line. Let us know if that helped or if you have already tried that ?

Answer (score 0):

It takes times to Propagate your modified dns entry to the Internet. New record will automatically replaced when your old record expires as defined in TTL. You have to wait time till TTL expires.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a very stupid and obvious one: My hoster had a UDP block on the machine active.

I assume Mac and Android use a fallback DNS server in case the one set is not reachable? That would explain the wrong (correct) results.

On a linux machine however, a nslookup / dig using the new DNS server resulted in a timeout.